# How to see if a .NET program is running

Tags: .net

Is it possible to determine if a Microsoft .NET program is running on a windows computer?

Comment: Do you mean a specific program to which you know the name or any program running on the computer that is .Net?

Comment: Your program or any .net program?

Comment: And whether it runs on Windows, or if it runs at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are attempting to identify processes/applications that are explicit to .NET, you should look for a dependency/module within the process that is specific to the .NET framework.

Below I am using `mscorlib`, as it's the first that comes to mind, as my hint to identify that the process is dependent on the .NET framework. e.g.

```
        var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (var process in processes)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var module in process.Modules)
                {
                    if (module.ToString().Contains("mscorlib"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(process);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { // Access violations }
        }
```

It's not bullet proof, as some processes cannot have their modules enumerated due to access restrictions, but if you run it, you'll see that it will pull back .NET dependent processes.  Perhaps it will give you a good starting point to get you thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

The following will return true if there is one or more processes running that have the supplied name.

```
    public bool IsProcessRunning(string processName)
    {
        return Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).Length != 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [CorPublishLibrary](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CorPublishLibrary.aspx) - a library that lets you interrogate all managed-code processes running on a machine.

[image]